"Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:50268/yZ6Ui9WuIGw=/ws "error
I am trying to run my flutter application on android virtual device using vs code but when I run the code it shows following error
I/xample.chalbha(11197): Waiting for a blocking GC ProfileSaver
and the app does not open and shows the blank screen .How to fix this issue
How can I solve this problem?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
